# Java Calendar. After function is not returning expected result

Tags: java, calendar

I have written the below code

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar expiry = Calendar.getInstance();
expiry.set(2014, 1, 15, 0, 0); 
now.after(expiry);
```

this is giving me false, today is 19th it should give true

Am I missing anything?

Comment: it is better to use the provided constants by the calendar class. as @peter.petrov has pointed out the 1 actually stands for FEBRUARY. `expiry.set(2014, Calendar.JANUARY, 15, 0, 0)` in this case. [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Month 1 is February, not January as you thought. Month 0 is for January.

(2) Also, I would call getTime() right before calling after() just to be on the safe side.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar expiry = Calendar.getInstance();
expiry.set(2014, 0, 15, 0, 0); 
expiry.getTime();
now.after(expiry);
```

Not sure if calling getTime() here is strictly needed though.

I am referring to this part of the JavaDoc.

*set(f, value) changes calendar field f to value. In addition, it sets an 

internal member variable to indicate that calendar field f has been changed. 

Although calendar field f is changed immediately, the calendar's time value 

in milliseconds is not recomputed until the next call to get(), getTime(),
getTimeInMillis(), add(), or roll() is made. Thus, multiple calls to set() 

do not trigger multiple, unnecessary computations. As a result of changing 

a calendar field using set(), other calendar fields may also change, depending 

on the calendar field, the calendar field value, and the calendar system. 

In addition, get(f) will not necessarily return value set by the call to 

the set method after the calendar fields have been recomputed. 

The specifics are determined by the concrete calendar class.*

Comment: getTime() shouldn't be needed, you can test it easily enough to be sure though.

Comment: @TimB OK... Well, I know that but I don't want to confirm it just by a particular test, you know. I mean I am not sure if the set method which the OP is using has this same characteristic which set(f, value) have. If it does, getTime() is needed, I guess. I am not sure myself.

Comment: @peter.petrov Look in the code or run a test to be sure, but I'd be very surprised if you do. The dirty flag will be checked and the time re-computed as soon as it tries to use the value.